# How to reduce sample and hold circuit drift

Tags: ltspice, leakage-current, sample-and-hold

I've built a sample and hold circuit on LTSpice, and the output will drift up at a rate of ~100mV/s.
Is there an obvious way to reduce this? Is this a function of the FET / opamp used?

The obvious choice would be to use a specific sample and hold IC, however part of this exercise is to build it from discreets + opamps.

I have messed around with the simulation adding in resistances here and there, adjusting components to see a change, but got nowhere with it.

[image: LTSpice Circuit Diagram of Filter]
V3 is `PULSE(0 5 0.1 0.001 0.001 0.02 0.41 20)`

[image: Output Stream]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there an obvious way to reduce this? Is this a function of the FET
> / op-amp used?*

The input bias current for the [op-amp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1800fa.pdf) is **typically** 25 nA and, that would cause the voltage across the sample capacitor (220 nF) to drift at a little over 100 mV / second. You can prove this by removing the op-amp and monitoring the voltage directly.

There may also be a few nA leakage from the JFET.

Comment: Would a discrete MOSFET leak more or less than a JFET?

Comment: Probably more @SteKulov but, the main problem is the op-amp.

Comment: That indeed does work. Thank you.